# sqlbulkcopy - does not allow DBNull.Value.?

Tags: vb.net, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying these 2 calls below but both of them returns me an exception Customer_ID does not allow DBNull.Value. but when I debug, I see that all my records have Customer_ID assigned. It is the only one as not nullable defined on my DB table. what is causing that error?

```
   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myBookingDataTable)

   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myBookingss.ToArray())
```

here is my entire code.

```
    Using myConnection As SqlConnection = _
                New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()


                Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
                  New SqlBulkCopy(My.Settings.ConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default)

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Booking"

                    Try
                        ' Write from the source to the destination.
                         bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myBookingDataTable)

                        'bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myBookingss.ToArray())

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

                    Finally

                        bulkCopy.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using
```

Comment: is the order of the field is source and target identical?

Comment: @Pleun: thank you very much for your help. It was the problem indeed. I am using dataset.xsd item to define datatable and although i added a fresh one, it was somehow not ordered as it supposed to be. But it is kind of strange why sqlbulkcopy is that much sensitive. can you make answer also that I accept your comment as correct answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the order of the fields in source and target are identical.